# How to remove posts in a PHP blog

Tags: php, html

I am making a online market style website and right now users are allowed to post their sales on it, but I want the admin role to be able to edit/delete posts. 
What I was thinking is like a small button in the corner of each "post". The thing is I don't know how to do it so each button is unique, maybe connect them by ID or something?

```
<?php
    include("../dbaccess.php");
    $conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
    if ($conn->connect_error) {
        die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
    }
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM market";
    $result = $conn->query($sql);
    if ($result->num_rows > 0 ) {
        while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){
            print("<div class='marketProducts'><h1 class='marketh1'>"
            . $row['id'] .$row['product'] . " - " . $row['price'] . "€</h1>"
            . "<p class='marketDescription'>" . $row['description'] 
            . "<p class='marketSeller'>" . $row['seller'] . "</p></div>");
        }
    }
    else{
        print("No active sales.");
    }
    $conn->close();
?>
```

Comment: You can add the link to the button which redirects to {YOUR_ADDRESS}/post/delete/{id} where {id} will be the primary key for the post that you want to delete and you can create a script for the same URL that runs the code to delete the post. If you're still confused I can write the code to make you understand.

Comment: Set a permission role in to your Database and gave every each user a rolle for example User A = User, User B = Supporter, User C = Admin. you can realize this with Numbers as Permission Pointers. 0 = User, 1 = Supporter and 2 = Admin or so.

Comment: Sidenote, your missing a `</p>`, you would see that if you made your life easier by not using concatenation, its ok to break out of php https://3v4l.org/1g932

Comment: @TauseefShah Yeah I don't have a "page" for each post, they are just listed on one single page, not sure of what you mean so I'd appreciate the help!

Answer (score 1):

Create a file named `{YOUR_OWN_DIRECTORY}/delete.php` and in this file write the logic to delete the post using id of the blog like this:

```
$id = $_GET['post_id'];
$query = $db->prepare('DELETE FROM table_name WHERE id = ?');
$query->bind_param('i', $id);
$query->execute();
/* And other code that you want */
```

And in the blogs view, you will be having a `php forloop` to show all the blogs. You can add a button anywhere with a link to the delete file with the id that you'll get by echoing like this

```
<?php foreach($blogs as $blog): ?>
/* Rest of your view code will be here, I am just writing the delete button code *.

<a href="{YOUR_OWN_DIRECTORY}/delete.php?post_id=<?php echo $blog['id']; ?>">

<button type="button">Delte</button>

</a>

<?php endforeach; ?>
```

And when the user clicks the button it will run the code form `delete.php` file.

I hope I got the question right and it helps!!!

Comment: Please, correct your answer. This is a mysql injection vulnerability